# How to store html form in database that some of the filed is dyanmically generated,So firstly clear i have need to store whole html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I  need to store whole html form in mysql db using php with dyanamically generated input box also need to store in db, firstly i am taking all html code in PHP varibale and store in db the data is stored in db,but problem is that if i  create any input box dyanamically it not stored.

```
 <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <SCRIPT language="javascript">
           var i=1;
            function add(type) 
            {
                var element = document.createElement("input");
                if(type=="text")
                {
                    element.setAttribute("type", type);
                    element.setAttribute("value", type);
                    element.setAttribute("name", "text-"+i);
                    i++;
                    $('#fooBar').append("<p style='width:130px;'contenteditable='true'></p>");
                    $("#fooBar").append(element);

                }
            }
        </SCRIPT>

    </HEAD>
        <BODY oncontextmenu="return false">
            <FORM name="dform" id="dformid">
            <H2>Dynamic Form Element</H2>

            <BR/>
            <SELECT name="element">
                <OPTION value="text">Textbox</OPTION>
            </SELECT>

            <INPUT type="button" value="Add Form Element" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"/>

            <span id="fooBar">
             </br>
            </span>
            </span>
            <!--<input type="text" id="boxx">
            <div id="d"></div>-->
            </FORM>
        </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: php render when you page load, but javascript element append when you click your button, right?  so you have to run ajax for input this html form to database. you can store whole from in a javascript variable & then you send it post via ajax, then you store it in your DB. clear?

Comment: Please Explain me with some sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**See this that how you can call ajax**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
       // Ajax Call 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(document.body).on('click', 'button.submittoDB', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var htmlForm = $('form#dformid').html();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: yourfilepath/ajax.php,
            data: {
                formData: htmlForm // you can get this data with $_POST['formData'] in your ajax.php file
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
            });
        });
    });


       var i=1;
        function add(type) 
        {
            var element = document.createElement("input");
            if(type=="text")
            {
                element.setAttribute("type", type);
                element.setAttribute("value", type);
                element.setAttribute("name", "text-"+i);
                i++;
                $('#fooBar').append("<p style='width:130px;'contenteditable='true'></p>");
                $("#fooBar").append(element);

            }
        }
    </SCRIPT>

</HEAD>
    <BODY oncontextmenu="return false">
        <FORM name="dform" id="dformid">
        <H2>Dynamic Form Element</H2>

        <BR/>
        <SELECT name="element">
            <OPTION value="text">Textbox</OPTION>
        </SELECT>

        <INPUT type="button" value="Add Form Element" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"/>

        <span id="fooBar">
         </br>
        </span>
        </span>
        <!--<input type="text" id="boxx">
        <div id="d"></div>-->
        </FORM>
        <button class="submittoDB">Submit</button>
    </BODY>
```

Comment: why whole html is not stored it only store   <h2>Dynamic Form Element</h2>

        <br>
        <select name="element">
            <option value="text">Textbox</option>
        </select>

        <input type="button" value="Add Form Element" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)">

        <span id="fooBar">
         <br>
        <p style="width:130px;" contenteditable="true"></p><input type="text" value="text" name="text-1"><p style="width:130px;" contenteditable="true"></p><input type="text" value="text" name="text-2"></span>

Comment: <BODY id="bid"> i have use this to and acess form within body

Comment: bro you are too genius,thank you very much for helping me

Comment: Thank you also, & i just give you just example, if you need whole form you just wrap this form with a another div like <div class="yourClass"><form></form></div>, then get it with javascript like var hstml = $('.yourClass').html();       if you got your answer mark your question as a complete.